# Saving variables that have been modified outside the class

Tags: java, class

I'm building a plugin for Bukkit with a number of different classes.
The main class loads information from different config files into public variables in the main class. When a person runs a command in the game, the main class sends handling for the command over to a different class here called `playerCommands` which is initialized using the main class `MineJobs`. So `handler = new playerCommands(this)`, basically. When `playerCommands` initializes, it pulls the public variables from `MineJobs` like so:

```
public class playerCommands implements CommandExecutor{
    private MineJobs Main;
    private Conf Config;
    private Lang Lang;
    private Map<String, Player> Players;
    private Map<String, Job> Jobs;
    private Map<Location, SignC> Signs;
    public playerCommands(MineJobs main) {
        Main = main;
        Config = main.Config;
        Lang = main.Lang;
        Players = main.Players;
        Jobs = main.Jobs;
        Signs = main.Signs;
    }
```

My question is: When I modify one of the private variables in `playerCommands`, will that modify the public variables in `MineJobs` so that I can call a save function there and not need to pass the variables back? Or do I need to define the variables differently?

Comment: If you call `Players.put("Jordan", new Player("michael jordan"));` then your `main` 's Players will also "know" about the change, since they refer to the same map. Is that your question ?

Answer (score 0):

No. You have to do it yourself. Use getters and setters instead and do the mirroring there. For example:

```
public void setConfig(Conf value) {
    Main.Config = value;
}

public Conf getConfig() {
    return Main.Config;
}
```

Comment: I've just read a few articles about how variables like mine are only references to memory locations that have the values; so I was asking if the way I was passing my variables around would cause my changes made from one class to mirror in another due to those memory addresses being the same for the variables.
I figured it would because I never called for a new instance of anything to my knowledge, but wanted to be sure.

Comment: Oh I didn't get your question correctly. kiruwka answered it for you.